# help me understand a part of the baum welch algorithm for hidden markov models

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, baum-welch

I am having troubles understanding a crucial part of the baum-welch algorithm in hidden markov models.

When we calculate zhe/digamma representing the probability of being in state i at timestep t and then transitioning to state j in timestep t+1 given all the observations we calculate it as:

$zhe_{t(i, j)} = \frac{alpha_{t}(i) * a_{i, j} * b_{j}(O_{t+1}) * Beta_{t+1}(j)}{\sum_{j=1}^Nalpha_{t}(k)}$

This is one way of expressing it, another way of expressing it is to take the numerator and sum over all j's and i's and have that as an denominator:

$zhe_{t(i, j)} = \frac{alpha_{t}(i) * a_{i, j} * b_{j}(O_{t+1}) * Beta_{t+1}(j)}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}alpha_{t}(i) * a_{i, j} * b_{j}(O_{t+1}) * Beta_{t+1}(j)}$

now here arises my confusion.. thirst of all are these two equal? the denominator should represent $P(O|lambda)$ thus the probability of seeing the observation sequence given the model.
This is the standard problem which we tackle by the backward/forward algorithm thus the 1st denominator seems to make sence, but can this also be calculated by the second denominator?

Thirdly, why do we have to divide it by this denominator, what is the intuition, what happens if we dont: will we not have a probability?